# Prevent Server side Python Timeout?

Tags: python, timeout

I have a website hosted by 1and1. On the server there is a folder with about 5,300 pictures. I have a python script that does some image processing. I want to run the python script on all of the pictures in the folder.

The only way I know to make the server run the script is to put the file on my site and then go to www.mysite.com/pythonscipt.py

This works decently, except I get an Error 500 message after the script has gone through only about 280 pictures (after about 10 seconds). I could just run the script 20 times, removing the processed pictures after each run, but I figured there is a better way to do it (I just don't know what it is).

Question: Is this actually a timeout error? If so, can I make the time until timeout longer?
Or, is there a better way to run the script (such that timeouts won't even be an issue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise asking the hosting service about it. Generally there will be a way to run scripts on the server.